# How to pass only selected rows data from Dash DataTable as callback Input (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash

I'm building an app that shows gathered screenshots of user activities to make ML data markup more efficient.

The main idea of the app is building a table with selectable rows, selection of which shows the specified screenshot to endpoint user.

Current build of the app shows good performance on small datasets (<2000 records), and much worse on bigger datasets (>10000 records).
I think that this problem is passing all data of the DataTable to the callback every time when row is selected.

```
@dash_app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('image', 'src'),
[dash.dependencies.Input('image-toggle', 'n_clicks'),
dash.dependencies.Input('tasks-table', 'selected_rows'),
dash.dependencies.Input('tasks-table', 'data'),])
def display_image(n_clicks, selected_rows, data):
   ...
```

**How can I pass data of selected row only?**

P.S.
Solution with one main DataFrame, that is stored in the memory of Dash app won't work, because multiple users should be able to work with different data that's being loaded into the app using Dropdown that used to select source csv file.